# ViewState problem in asp.net Wizard control

Tags: asp.net

We are using an ASP.NET (2.0) Wizard control where on each wizard step the user fills in a few fields.

We have found that sometimes for some odd reason the value of the fields in previously filled steps is lost when "postbacking" to another step.

This problem seems to occur randomly; sometimes some of the field values are retained and others are lost.

The EnableViewState is true for the Page and all controls.

What are we overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of things happen when use Update Panel. In that case, U need to update the update panel.